# Javascript: Disabling drop-down based on other drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript function in my website. I don't know Javascript very well but, I want to modify it.

This section loads a third drop box, depending on the first two.

I want to modify it to disable the third one if the second drop box `locatie`'s value is `util`.

```
jQuery( function () {
  jQuery("#util, #loc").change( function() {
    var locatie =  jQuery("#loc").val();
    var utilitate = jQuery("#util").val();

    if ( (locatie!= '---') && (utilitate!='---') ) 

        jQuery.getJSON("index.php?option=com_calculator&opt=json_contor&format=raw",{ locatie: locatie, utilitate: utilitate }, function (data) {
                var html = "";

                html += "<option name=den_contor value ='contor' >Alege Contorul</option>";
                if ( data.success == 'ok' ) 
                for (var i in data.val) 
                    html += "<option name=den_contor value ='"+ i+"' >" + data.val[i]+ " </option>";
                jQuery("#den_contor").html( html )    

        })

     })
  });`
```

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: Maybe start voting. You've accepted some answers, so you've clearly found them useful.

Comment: "Javascript question" is a rather unhelpful question title.

Comment: @TRiG Agree. I'm not sure whether my proposal is much better, though :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
jQuery( function () {
  jQuery("#util, #loc").change( function() {
    var locatie =  jQuery("#loc").val();
    var utilitate = jQuery("#util").val();

    if ( (locatie!= '---') && (utilitate!='---') ) 

        jQuery.getJSON("index.php?option=com_calculator&opt=json_contor&format=raw",{ locatie: locatie, utilitate: utilitate }, function (data) {
                var html = "";

                html += "<option name=den_contor value ='contor' >Alege Contorul</option>";
                if ( data.success == 'ok' ) 
                for (var i in data.val) {
                    if (i != 'locatie' && data.val[i] != 'util') {
                        html += "<option name=den_contor value ='"+ i+"' >" + data.val[i]+ " </option>";
                    }
                }
                jQuery("#den_contor").html( html )    

        })

     })
  });
```

I added the line that starts with `if (i != 'locatie'` which checks to make sure that you are **not** looking at the `locatie` item and that the value is **not** `util`. If these are both true (ie. not locatie and not util) then we display the 3rd drop down.

Comment: thanks Blair for your reply. it works but not quite like i wanted it to work. in the second drop box i have A, B, C, D. if the user chooses A, there is no need for an third box, so i want to disable the box (no element, or not even show up) or to change the text that appears in --- or something like that. if B, C or D is chosen to add an first element with the 'Alege contorul' text with no value.

Comment: Ahh ok. I've updated the code then. I thought you wanted it disabled, rather than remove.